# What means "veteran bores"

Tags: meaning

The Great Gatsby by F. Scott Fitzgerald
"In consequence, I'm inclined to reserve all judgments, a habit that has opened up many curious natures to me and also made me the victim of not a few veteran bores."
What means "veteran bores"?
I was confused by "veteran" from the war.

Comment: Can you edit to tell us what you found when you looked for "veteran" and "bore" in your dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about veterans, one of the literal meanings is somebody who has fought in a war, as you already know. It can also mean somebody who has the experience of doing something or has done it for a long time. The second meaning is the one F. Scott Fitzgerald is using. He means that since he doesn't judge what people are saying to him he sometimes has to listen to people who are boring and have been boring others for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Cambridge online dictionary:
veteran = a person who has had a lot of experience of a particular activity,
bore = to talk or act in a way that makes someone lose interest, 
=========================================================== 
Conclusion, "veteran bores" means: lot of experience to talk or act in a way that makes someone lose interest

Comment: Your conclusion sentence is unclear.  Can you improve the clarity of this answer?